# Show specific parts of masterpage depending on user group

Tags: master-page, groups, view

I've my custom masterpage in SharePoint application, it has my custom menu, something like:

```
<ul>
<li> option 1</li>
<li> option 2</li>
<li> option 3</li>
etc...
</ul>
```

and also I have two user groups: groupA and groupB

How can I show option 1 only for groupA members and option 2 only for groupB members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different permission levels for each of those group, you can wrap your content in an SPSecurityTrimmedControl. This will show/hide content for users based on their level of access.

Unfortunately this will not work based on group name, only the resulting permissions that users have from being in a group, so if both groups have the same permission levels then this won't work.

The other alternative would be audience targetting, which can work purely based on group membership. This is a little tricky when you are talking about HTML content in a master page, but can be done through Javascript (with a little help from SPServices). Note: this isn't an effective security measure, it is NOT denying users access to content, it is only customising the display of content.

This blog helpfully describes both methods: https://blog.imason.com/4-ways-to-target-content-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Audience targeting in JS resolved my problems. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the [SPSecurityTrimmedControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.permissionsstring.aspx) if there is a permission difference in the 2 groups.

```
<ul>
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl PermissionsString="OpenItems" runat="server"> 
    <li>Option 1</li>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl PermissionsString="ManageLists" runat="server"> 
    <li>Option 2</li>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the menu using JavaScript.

Then you can use Client Object Model to check the group of the user. If you need help to check the group with JavaScript, try this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122139/check-if-current-users-belongs-to-sp-group-using-javascript-client-side-object-m